# How to set Selenium webdriver.reap_profile in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I've searched Selenium docs but I can't find how to set in c# webdriver.reap_profile property for FirefoxDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary profiles created for the FirefoxDriver are always deleted in the .NET bindings, as long as the IWebDriver.Quit() method is properly called on the driver object. If the driver is properly disposed of and the profile is not deleted, it's a bug. If you want the option to retain the profiles, that would have to be an enhancement to the current project.

Comment: I need this option because it speeds up execution of tests, i.e. temporary Firefox profile is created for every test by Selenium.